# Как получить размер view после применения constraints

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Для примера есть пустой single-view проект. В основном view, создан один view и с помощью IB constraints привязан к границам на расстоянии 20.

Во ViewController'е, в методе viewDidLoad делаю вывод в консоль:

```
NSLog(@"%f %f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
NSLog(@"%f %f", testView.frame.size.width, testView.frame.size.height);
```

Результат после запуска в симуляторе iPhone4:

```
320.000000 480.000000 - разрешение экрана
280.000000 528.000000 - размер testView
```

Размер не правильный, хотя отображается всё корректно. Правильный размер 280х440.

В каком методе работать с размерами testView, чтобы они были корректными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы вьюхи отвечающие за рендеринг:

```
 - (void)setNeedsLayout;//Сетим флажок что нужно пересчитать лайауты при следующем цикле ранлупа при перерисовке экрана.
 - (void)layoutSubviews;//Метод вызываетя при перерисовки экрана, здесь обычно задавались раньше фреймы для новых позиций вьюх, сейчас после вызова супера  можно брать новые фреймы так как вызывается после -(void)updateConstraints;
 - (BOOL)needsUpdateConstraints;//Проверка флага на перещет констрайнов.
 - (void)layoutIfNeeded; //Перериосвать лайауты если поставлен флажок методом  - (void)setNeedsLayout;
 - (void)setNeedsUpdateConstraints; // Вызывается если нужно зафиксировать изменение констрайнов, для следующего пересчета в ранлупе.
 - (void)updateConstraints;//Метод вызывается для перемчета констрайнов. Обычно тут его перегружают для задания новых констрейнов и анимации.
```

Для UIViewController есть методы:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews; // Ща будут пересчитаны лайауты у вьюхи контроллера.
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews;// Пересчитаны лайауты у вьюхи контроллера.
```

Для справки ViewDidLoad метод, вызывается когда вьюха загружена, а вам еще нужно поместить ее в иерархию вьюх и на экран, только тогда можно узнать размеры фреймов. Почитайте  документацию про методы контроллера:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Пишу по памяти лучше в документации почитайте про эти методы.

Comment: Спасибо. Затупил и не посмотрел методы связанные с layout'ами. Перехожу на следующий этап борьбы с autoLayout.